# How to stop a Postgres script when it encounters an error?

Tags: database, postgresql, error-handling, psql, sql-scripts

Is there a way to specify that when executing a sql script it stops when encountering the first error on the script, it usually continues, regardless of previous errors.

Comment: If you run it from the terminal you can do `psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=on [FLAGS] -f file_name`

Answer (score 223):

I think the solution to add following to .psqlrc is far from perfection

```
\set ON_ERROR_STOP on
```

there exists much more simple and convenient way - use psql with parameter:

```
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1
```

better to use also `-X` parameter turning off .psqlrc file usage.
Works perfectly for me

p.s. the solution found in great post from Peter Eisentraut. Thank you, Peter!
http://petereisentraut.blogspot.com/2010/03/running-sql-scripts-with-psql.html

Comment: `-v ON_ERROR_STOP=ON` also works, at least with 9.2. I suspect any of the [variants of boolean "true"](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-boolean.html) are allowed.

Comment: It doesn't work in interactive mode, which confused me for a minute.

Comment: Without "on" explicitly set, it will toggle. This bit me when I had a script working great and then broke it into several scripts that all ran the same initialization script. Then, the subscripts were toggling this parameter on and off. :(

Answer (score 34):

I assume you are using `psql`, this might be handy to add to your `~/.psqlrc` file.

```
\set ON_ERROR_STOP on
```

This will make it abort on the first error. If you don't have it, even with a transaction it will keep executing your script but fail on everything until the end of your script.

And you probably want to use a transaction as Paul said. Which also can be done with `psql --single-transaction ...` if you don't want to alter the script.

So a complete example, with ON_ERROR_STOP in your .psqlrc:

```
psql --single-transaction --file /your/script.sql
```

Comment: Even if the transaction fails, the exit status of the psql command is still 0.

Comment: Indeed, even if `--single-transaction` is used,  `-v ON_ERROR_STOP=1` is still necessary for a non zero exist status

Answer (score 9):

It's not exactly what you want, but if you start your script with `begin transaction;` and end with `end transaction;`, it will actually skip everything after the first error, and then it will rollback everything it did before the error.

Comment: True, but, it still parses everything.  And if you want to do a *second* transaction only if the first succeeded, this won't work.

Comment: Yes, and not to forget continuing when it encounters DDL Create table errrors...  (version:  postrgres 10).  Yes, it skips one table and goes onto the others...

Answer (score 2):

I always like to reference the manual directly.

From the [PostgreSQL Manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html):

> Exit Status
>
> psql returns 0 to the shell if it finished normally, 1 if a fatal
>   error of its own occurs (e.g. out of memory, file not found), 2 if the
>   connection to the server went bad and the session was not interactive,
>   and 3 if an error occurred in a script and the variable
>   ON_ERROR_STOP was set.

By default if the sql code you are running on the PostgreSQL server error psql won't quit an error.  It will catch the error and continue.  If, as mentioned above, you set the `ON_ERROR_STOP` setting to on, when psql catches an error in the sql code it will exit and return `3` to the shell.

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can enable [ON_ERROR_STOP](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-VARIABLES-ON-ERROR-STOP) which is `off` by default when you log in with the user `john` and the database `apple` as shown below. *`ON_ERROR_STOP` is `off` automatically after logout:

```
psql -U john -v ON_ERROR_STOP=on apple
```

```
psql -U john --variable=ON_ERROR_STOP=on apple
```

```
psql -U john --set=ON_ERROR_STOP=on apple
```

And, you can enable `ON_ERROR_STOP` when you run a script from the file `test.sql` as shown below:

```
psql -U john -v ON_ERROR_STOP=on -f test.sql apple
```

And, you can enable `ON_ERROR_STOP` after login as shown below:

```sql
\set ON_ERROR_STOP on
```

Or. *This command can only enable `ON_ERROR_STOP` without toggling `on` and `off`:

```sql
\set ON_ERROR_STOP
```

And, you can show the value of `ON_ERROR_STOP` with [\echo](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMAND-ECHO) as shown below. *Don't forget to put `:` just before `ON_ERROR_STOP`:

```sql
postgres=# \echo :ON_ERROR_STOP
on
```

*Memos:

- Don't use the lowercase `on_error_stop` which doesn't work.
- You can enable `ON_ERROR_STOP` with `oN`, `1`, `TrUe`, `tR`, etc.
- You can disable `ON_ERROR_STOP` with `oFf`, `0`, `FaLsE`, `fA`, etc.
- It happens that error doesn't stop execution when you run a script from a file.
- [RAISE statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) with `DEBUG`, `LOG`, `INFO`, `NOTICE` or `WARNING` cannot stop execution even if `ON_ERROR_STOP` is `on` while `RAISE` statement with `EXCEPTION` or nothing can. *[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77771467/enabling-on-error-stop-doesnt-work-with-raise-statement-in-postgresql) explains it in detail.