# Deploy postgres via jenkins - continuous integration/deployment

Tags: postgresql, jenkins, deployment, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment

I got my database dump (tables, functions, triggers etc) in *.sql files.
At this moment I am deploying them via jenkins, by passing execute shell command:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -d my_db < /[path_to_my_file].sql
```

The problem is, that if something is wrong in my sql file, build finishes as SUCCESS. I would like to got information immediately if something fails, without looking into log and checking if every command executed succesfully.

Is it possible (and how if the answer is 'yes') to deploy postgres database via jenkins other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my execution command to:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -d my_db < [path_to_file].sql
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have set
    `set -e`
Before running the command.
If that does not work, I'd look at the return code from the command above. That can be done by running 
    `echo $?`
right after the command.

If that gives you a zero when it fails it's postgres fault (sice it should return with something else than 0 on fail).

Perhaps there is a postgres flag to fail on wrong input.

EDIT:
    `-v ON_ERROR_STOP=1`
As a flag to postgres should make postgres fail on errors

Comment: Both solutions doesn't work:   ERROR:  insert or update on table "quantity_audit" violates foreign key constraint "quantity_audit_product_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (product_id)=(5) is not present in table "products".
INSERT 0 1
+ echo 0
0
Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: Then postgres is to blame. Here is a thread where they might have your solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480381/postgres-sql-fail-on-script-error

Comment: Works :) Thank you