# Enabling `ON_ERROR_STOP` doesn't work with `RAISE` statement in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, raise, raiseerror

First, I enabled [ON_ERROR_STOP](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-VARIABLES-ON-ERROR-STOP) to stop the execution immediately after error as shown below:

```sql
\set ON_ERROR_STOP on
```

Because [the doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-VARIABLES-ON-ERROR-STOP) about `ON_ERROR_STOP` says below:

> By default, command processing continues after an error. When this variable is set to on, processing will instead stop immediately

So, I created `test` table with `num` column, then inserted the row whose `num` is `0` as shown below:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (
  num INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO test (num) VALUES (0);
```

Then, I ran the script which raises `INFO` error with [RAISE statement](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html) then, increments `num` in `test` table by 1 as shown below. *I also tried `RAISE` statement with `DEBUG`, `LOG`, `NOTICE`, `WARNING`, `EXCEPTION` or nothing:

```sql
DO LANGUAGE plpgsql $$
BEGIN
  RAISE INFO 'A custom error!';
  UPDATE test SET num = num + 1;
END
$$;
```

But, `num` was incremented to `1` as shown below. *`num` was not incremented to `1` only with `EXCEPTION` or nothing:

```sql
postgres=# SELECT num FROM test;
 num
-----
   1
(1 row)
```

So, how can I make `ON_ERROR_STOP` work with `RAISE` statement properly?

Comment: 1) From [Reporting Errors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RAISE): *EXCEPTION raises an error (which normally aborts the current transaction); the other levels only generate messages of different priority levels.* 2) It works for me if I use `RAISE EXCEPTION`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver So, enabling `ON_ERROR_STOP` doesn't affect to the behaviour of `INFO`, `DEBUG`, `LOG`, `NOTICE` and `WARNING` errors? I mean enabling `ON_ERROR_STOP` doesn't stop `INFO`, `DEBUG`, `LOG`, `NOTICE` and `WARNING` errors immediately after error?

Comment: Yes, because as the docs state they are not errors they are just messages.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I thought `INFO`, `DEBUG`, `LOG`, `NOTICE` and `WARNING` were errors because the doc says `The level option specifies the error severity`.

Comment: Yes but `EXCEPTION` is the only one that actually raises an error.

Comment: From the manual: `EXCEPTION raises an error (which normally aborts the current transaction); the other levels only generate messages of different priority levels.` See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RAISE